# Number or name of Virtual Desktop that I'm currently using

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-desktop

I'm using Virtual Desktops in Windows 10 a lot. Surprisingly it works nicely even with large number of them open.

The only thing problem is that I can find no way to see which Virtual Desktop I'm in. How can I see this?

I just need the number or name of Virtual Desktop that I'm in.

Answer (score 7):

To display the virtual desktop number in the icon tray (and on the screen when switching), you can try the simple and lightweight app Windows Virtual Desktop Helper:

https://github.com/dankrusi/WindowsVirtualDesktopHelper

[image: Windows Virtual Desktop Helper Screenshot]

It's free, stable and has a clean design.

Full disclosure: I am the author of Windows Virtual Desktop Helper

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the built-in functionality in Windows 10, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> opens the Task View. The task view will show the desktop ID's at the top, numbered from left to right.

[image]

The desktop on the task-view which isn't greyed is the desktop you're currently on.

Alternatively, there's a 3rd party application called VirtualDesktopManager which is a small Windows program that adds an icon to the system tray, that indicates which virtual desktop you are currently on. It's available from https://github.com/m0ngr31/VirtualDesktopManager/releases